# ImportError: No module named django.mongo_auth

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

When trying to setup environment to run django-nonrel and mongoengine, I keep getting following error. The project runs fine on different computer where it was developed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
enter code hereFile "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/home/test/Documents/personal-proj/groc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
app = import_module(appname)

File "/home/test/Documents/personal-proj/groc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)

ImportError: No module named django.mongo_auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
pip install django-mongo-auth
```

Since you are setting it up in a new environment you will need to make sure you have all the dependencies installed.  If you have an up to date requirements.txt file, you can also run:

```
pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt
```

And you can view what packages you are currently using by using:

```
pip freeze
```